# Is it possible to build ionic apps on the adobe phonegap build server?

Tags: cordova, build, ionic-framework, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm looking for a build service for ionic, but i found just a service for phoneGap. 
Since Ionic is based on cordova i wanted to ask if it is possible to build ionic over adobes phonegap builder: 
[image]
[Website](https://build.phonegap.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formerly I used to develop an Ionic project and made all the development with it. When I needed to test something on the phone, I was using the Phonegap Build.

Both projects have the folder "www". To use Phonegap Build site, I was replacing the folder "www" of Phonegap project with the "www" folder of Ionic project. Then just send the Phonegap project ZIP to Phonegap Build site. This always worked for me.

After creating the project (phonegap create my-app), basically you do the project at "www" folder and configures preferences in config.xml (fullscreen, plashScreen, android-minSdkVersion, etc).

If you use Phonegap Build site you don´t need to add platforms (platform phonegap add) and not need to run "phonegap run android"

PhoneGap Build's only requirement for your application structure is that the config.xml and index.html is in the top level of your application.

Make test: - phonegap create my-app - configure config.xml (If necessary, not required) - config.xml and index.html in the same folder (preferably in www) - ZIP - Upload ZIP on Phonegap Build

Today I recommend you do the build using the Ionic

Comment: Did you find a similar service for ionic?

Comment: Similar service online (Website) no! But there is Ionic Lab for Windows where you can create, build, test, and deploy Ionic apps

Comment: Do you have any links to the downloads?

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I'll make a webservice on my own ;)